# Auto Delete Hidden File when USB Connected?

Tags: applescript, macos, usb

I have a MacAir running El Capitan with all updates. I use a USB stick to move movies from Mac to Samsung Smart TV. The TV writes a hidden file " .device_info_*** " (long abstract filename). This file keeps details of movie folders in it... but does not update. So when I delete a movie... the folder stays hidden on the stick in this file and shows again when connected to the TV. I have created a work around by showing hidden files and deleting this file... the old folder info disappears when viewing on the TV and the TV writes a new file when USB is reinserted. But the whole process starts all over again.

I want to have an auto script that deletes the .device_info_*** file every time the USB is connected to my MacAir - without any user interface or questions about "are you sure, etc" . The asterisks in my example are wildcards because the filenames created are different every time (after the .device_info_ part of the name).

What script would do this? And can wild cards be used as part of the filename in the script?

I am not a script writer but am pretty savvy.

Comment: I also empty Trash of course... and run Clean My Mac & Clean My Drive (which does find garbage) but still the folders hide in the .device_info_* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) script that deletes a file when a partition is mounted:

[image]

If you want wildcards, it might be more useful to use a script action with rm:

```
rm /Volumes/volumename/.file*
```

Comment: Thank you. I will need the use of wildcards because the Samsung TV sets a new filename every time... the beginning is the same:   .device_info_ ...followed by an alpha numeric sequence - this is the current one .device_info_1db59465-b03a-41e6-862a-f342d49e84ff

Comment: Also - will this auto execute when the USB is inserted/connected to the Mac?

Comment: I just tried the Terminal Command rm /Volumes/volumename/.device_info_*

Comment: and it came back that file does not exist... probably because it is hidden (although I can see it with hidden files set to show). Thanks again.

Comment: @ElMarinero Yes, it will auto execute on mounting. Terminal will always be able to see/delete hidden files because there's not really as such in the shell (it's just how Finder represents the file). Make sure the path is correct and drag the file into Terminal to show the path, escaping spaces as necessary.

Comment: I changed the volume name to eliminate spaces and it worked... so will this stay resident now and always run?

Comment: @ElMarinero Yes, it should. If you want to use spaces in a Terminal command, escape them with a backslash before the space (e.g. `volume\ name`).

Comment: The script works (with no spaces in the filename) ... but does not auto execute when the disc is remounted/inserted. There must be another line of script that calls for the command line when the disc is inserted?

Comment: @ElMarinero You need to use Keyboard Maestro per my answer, replacing the Delete File action in the screenshot with the Execute Shell Script action and it's contents being the shell script beginning 'rm'.

Comment: Thanks again... that works as well... just not familiar with Keyboard Maestro... (free version) ... how / where do I save to have it resident on my mac and auto execute? There are some Export Options in the menus..?

Comment: @ElMarinero Keyboard Maestro has a daemon that runs continuously. You can quit the editor and the macros will still run (see the menu bar icon).

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you very much - you have been very helpful. One more question... can I have more than one Volume Name in the command? I have 2 USB discs that I use in the same TV. I'm curious if I can include both in one macro / command (using an and/or type of command) or of I need to make two separate macros?

Comment: @ElMarinero The easiest thing is probably just to duplicate the macro and change the volume name in the trigger and in the delete action.

Comment: Thanks again - all sorted. You have been terrific... can I register a vote for you? I'm new to this forum.

Comment: @ElMarinero Thanks! As the question author, you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons on the left. [Once you earn 15 reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), you are able to change the visible vote score using the up and down buttons.